# Report on the top 20% of Customers Only

Tags: apex, reporting, batch

I need to report only on Contacts who are contributing to the top 20% of revenue.  Payment is stored on Customer which is a Master-Detail to Contact, one Contact can be a Customer multiple times.  In practice this means that Customer is an instance of a sale/service, and multiple Customers who have the same Contact must be aggregated to determine if that Contact contributed to the top 20% of revenue.

I can group by Customer and order by the sum of payment in Salesforce Reporting, however, I cannot limit/filter the results by an aggregate formula (# of Contacts * 0.20).

As a workaround I have created a batch class that runs every night and "flags" a record as a top 20% contributor, then I filter results on my report by that flag == true.

The problem with this method is it creates extraneous data in the database and is very limited in scope.  The time period for reporting is fixed to the value I used in the batch class to flag records as top 20% contributors (in this case the last fiscal quarter).  Is there a better way to do this within Salesforce?

Comment: is 'payment' stored on Customer per quarter or only for the most recent last closed quarter?

Comment: Can you post some code from your batch class so we can better understand how you are currently calculating whether someone is in the top 20%?

Comment: I probably should have specified better.  Payment is stored on Customer and Customer is an instance of a service/sale.  Payment is not quarterly, more like a point of sale transaction.

Comment: How do you calculate whether someone contributed to the top 20% of revenue? Are you trying to get the 20% of customers who purchased the most in a given time frame? Why can't you just get all customers, sort in excel, and keep the top 20%? Or am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: This report must be run in Salesforce Reporting, I am calculating the top 20% of revenue by summing the Payment of all Customer records that have the same Contact ID then dividing by the total number of Contacts.  I then flag these Contacts with a Boolean so that I can filter by the Boolean during reporting.